# popping sound when pedaling

Tags: mountain-bike

I locate the source of the popping noise to be around the hub. So far I think I lubricated everything I can get my hands on. The noise is constant and it happens at all gears. I know it's not the chain because I fixed it yesterday when it was clicking, now the clicking noise is gone. I know it's not the crank neither because I lubricated the nuts and bolts there too. Also I put my ears next to the crank and the noise doesn't come from there. I want to ask the question here before I bring it to the shop because I run out of things to lubricate or maybe it's something I have no idea about.
Thanks.

Comment: Here's the link to the video. https://youtu.be/JDLYecEBFso

Comment: Is the noise there when you rotate the wheel by hand directly in both directions, i.e. without touching the cranks? If it's a new bike I would bring it back to the shop so they can have a look at it.

Comment: No, the noise is not there when I rotated the wheel by hand. The noise as you hear from the video only comes when I rotate using the pedal.

Comment: Maybe the b-tension needs to be adjusted. If the guide pulley is too close from the cogs, the chain may cause a rattling sound.